# Python 2.7 Probability Histogram with Line of Best Fit Won't Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram from a long list of probabilities using this code:

```
#create a histogram showing the probability distribution for the triangles
n, bins, patches=plt.hist([prob_long], bins=[0.36,0.365,0.37,0.375,0.38,0.385,0.39,0.395,0.40,0.405,0.41,0.415,0.42,0.425,0.43,0.435,0.44,0.445,0.45,0.455,0.46,0.465,0.47,0.475,0.48,0.485,0.49,0.495,0.5], normed=(True), facecolor='orange', alpha=0.75, ec='black')

#plot a line of best fit
(mu,sigma)=norm.fit(prob_long)
y=mlab.normpdf( bins, mu, sigma)
l=plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)

plt.xlabel('Probabilities')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title("""Histogram of the probability distribution of the longest side 
of Pythagorean triples""")
plt.xlim([0.35,0.50])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I first used a set value for the bins but it just gave me one bar on the histogram so I entered the values myself. Now it gives me a variety of probabilities but the frequencies are all at 200 for reasons unbeknownst to me. Here is a picture of the histogram I get:

[image: Here]

Comment: Using your exact code after generating random numbers with `prob_long = np.random.uniform(0.36, 0.5, size=1000)` works as intended for me (I get bars of different heights and the normal pdf as a red dashed line).